# Django template - hide a form if a specific item is selected in another form

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, hide

I have two forms like these (each one is a drop-down menu), used for creating a model:

```
<label for="id_section" ><strong>text</strong></label> 

{{ form.section }}                

<label for="id_area" ><strong>text</strong></label>

{{ form.area }}
```

I want to hide the second form if a specific item in the first one is selected.
There is a way to accomplish this using django tags and filters and javascript, and not only with javascript?

[edit] Solution with js:

```
var selectOne = document.getElementById("id_section");

selectOne.addEventListener("change", function() {
if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'value'){
    document.getElementById('id_area').style.display = "none";
} else {
    document.getElementById('id_area').style.display = "inline";
            }
        }, false);
```

Comment: have you tried something yet? a javascript could have a click listener on the first form and if the specific value is selected , "id_area" gets hidden... may this be an idea? or are you looking for something different?

Comment: I've updated the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this with jquery:

```
$('#id_section').change(function() {
    $(this).val() == 'something') ? $('#id_area').hide() : $('#id_area').show();       
});
```